# Проверка пароля по символьно на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

Как сделать проверку пароля в режиме живого времени посимвольно? Т.е. если 3-ий символ отличен от введенного пароля, выводится сообщение - "пароли не совпадают" и т.д.

Есть скрипт простой проверки пароля:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function valid(){
   if (document.getElementById('password').value != document.getElementById('checkPass').value) {
    alert('Пароли не совпадают');
    return false; 
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример. 
Алерт не прыгает если удаляем внесенную проверку пароля.

```js
function valid(event){
var pas = document.getElementById('password').value 
var cpas = document.getElementById('checkPass').value
for(i=0;i < cpas.length; i++)
{

 if(pas[i] != cpas[i] && event.keyCode != 8)
 {
   alert('Пароли не совпадают');
   break;
 }
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="password">
<input type="text" id="checkPass" onkeyup="valid(event)">
```

Comment: отлично! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: you welcome :))